# Jetson Nano: Gstreamer inside docker container

Tags: docker, gstreamer, yocto, gstreamer-1.0, nvidia-jetson

I've managed to install and use docker with CUDA access on the Nvidia Jetson Nano device. The device is running a custom Yocto/poky-zeus (JetPack 4.3 supported) build .

The docker image that I am testing with is an official [nvidia-l4t-base](https://ngc.nvidia.com/catalog/containers/nvidia:l4t-base) image for Arm64 Nvidia Jetson devices.

I am running the docker container with the following line:

`docker run --net=host --runtime nvidia --rm --ipc=host -v /tmp/.X11-unix/:/tmp/.X11-unix/ -v /tmp/argus_socket:/tmp/argus_socket --device=/dev/video0:/dev/video0 --cap-add SYS_PTRACE -e DISPLAY=:0 -it nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-base:r32.3.1`

Which is proven to work on the official tegraflash image from NVIDIA SDK-manager (JetPack 4.3).

I can run gstreamer (1.14 or 1.16) just fine *outside* the docker container, but attempting to run any gstreamer(1.14) stuff inside the docker image fails.

For instance, when running this gstreamer pipeline:

`gst-launch-1.0 -e nvarguscamerasrc num-buffers=-1 ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, format=(string)NV12, framerate=(fraction)60/1' ! nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! nvvidconv ! nvegltransform ! udpsink host=$HOST_IP port=$GST_PORT`

it fails with the following error:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
[ 2415.341857] (NULL device *): nvhost_channelctl: invalid cmd 0x80685600
[ 2415.350034] (NULL device *): nvhost_channelctl: invalid cmd 0x80685600
[ 2415.357153] (NULL device *): nvhost_channelctl: invalid cmd 0x80685600
Failed to query video capabilities: Inappropriate ioctl for device
libv4l2: error getting capabilities: Inappropriate ioctl for device
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/nvv4l2h264enc:nvv4l2h264enc0: Error getting capabilities for device '/dev/nvhost-msenc': It isn't a v4l2 driver. Check if it is a v4l1 driver.
Additional debug info:
v4l2_calls.c(98): gst_v4l2_get_capabilities (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/nvv4l2h264enc:nvv4l2h264enc0:
system error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Changing the encoding just gives another error. But this pipeline works just fine outside the docker as well as *inside* the docker on the official NVIDIA SDK-manager image, but NOT inside docker container with the Yocto build.

Camera access is there in the container (RPi CSI camera), as `v4l2-ctl --all` shows correct information.

Any idea on how to fix this?

More on this issue from the [meta-tegra layer](https://github.com/madisongh/meta-tegra/issues/230) and on [Nvidia-docker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1202#issue-570584835) issues.

Comment: Did you find the solution, I am having similar issue?

Comment: I was unfortunately not able to continue this project due to me being needed elsewhere.. But didn't they fix this in issue https://github.com/madisongh/meta-tegra/issues/230? I know a lot of issues with using Docker on the Jetson Nano has been fixed through this issue thread, so maybe take a look there :)